# Not modifying to relative path in twig

Tags: twig, phpstorm

I'm using `Twig` in `PhpStorm`. I marked `template` folder as `Resource Root`. Here is my folder structure in `template` folder:

```
template
> blog
>> index.twig
> common
>> default-layout.twig
```

My `index.twig` file extends `default-layout.twig`

```
{% extends './common/default-layout.twig' %}
```

Autocompletion in PhpStorm works fine. But when I change file name for example `default-layout2.twig` PhpStorm changes `index.twig` to:

```
{% extends '../common/default-layout2.twig' %}
```

This causes errors with twig `Looks like you try to load a template outside configured directories`

Is there something I can do with that? How to force PhpStorm not to change `./` to `../` ?

Comment: Just don't place `./` in front of the template location?

Comment: *"But when I change file name..."* Are you referring to the `Refactor | Rename` action? You may unselect some checkboxes there so IDE does not look for such file names in the project files and therefore it will not modify such paths (although I would not expect it to change such path style anyway). If you do so (and that's what is causing such changes in first place) then you would need to manually change such file references (Find & Replace in Path).

Comment: Other than that: do what DarkBee said: do not put `./` there. Your framework/project runtime, if configured appropriately will know where to look for the files and `./` is not needed there (works just fine for me in custom project where Twig templates are used).

Comment: Even without './' phpStorm is modyfing path to '../'